# robot framework selenium standalone Only Java Installed

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, robotframework, automated-tests

I need some help setting up a Robot Framework with Selenium - both standalone.
My configuration is Jenkins + RobotFramework + Selenium all in Standalone Mode.

I Want to preconfigure a Job using a test set that is shipped with my self made bundle. In the end I want to make jenkins Job that comes with the selfmade package bundle to something like a automated installation qualification.

Everything starts up fine but my test can not load the selenium libs for web test, my last attemp was the following:
-Start Jenkins

```
java -DJENKINS_HOME="%~dp0\jenkins_home" -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081 --webroot="%~dp0\jenkins"
```

-Start Selenium Server

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar
```

-Start Robot Job in Jenkins

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:selenium-2.45.0/*.jar:selenium-2.45.0/libs/*.jar -jar %JENKINS_HOME%\jenkins_home\robotframework-2.8.7.jar %JENKINS_HOME%\jenkins_home\tests\myTest.txt
```

Sadly I am facing an error : "Importing test library 'Selenium2Library' failed: ImportError: No module named Selenium2Library"
I tried several approaches to get it running.

Because of some preconditions I can not manipulate the contens of the Robot oder any othe .jar
Slowly I feel this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your test obviously requires Selenium2Library which is not a standard RF library and needs to be installed/downloaded separately.

In this case (running RF from standalone jar) you need the java version of Selenium2Library which can be downloaded [from here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/markusbernhardt/robotframework-selenium2library-java/1.4.0.6/robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar).

If you have all three jars in a directory you could run your tests from that directory like this:

```
java -cp robotframework-2.8.7.jar;robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar org.robotframework.RobotFramework  %JENKINS_HOME%\jenkins_home\tests\myTest.txt
```

(looks like you are on Windows - otherwise use : as classpath separator)

Comment: Yes I am on windows - I also found out a different solution, I will also try the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I simply unpacked the selenium .tar package and took out the Libs and put them into %jenkins_home%\Lib\SeleniumLibrary\
This worked for me.